# magento 2 - Access denied for user - cache problem

Tags: magento2, database, cache

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'aromacak_db30'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/aromacakes/test.aromacakes.online/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml on line 84

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'aromacak_db30'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/aromacakes/test.aroma.online/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml on line 84
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'mysqli_connect(...', '/home/aromacake...', 84, Array)
#1 /home/aromacakes/test.aroma.online/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml(84): mysqli_connect('localhost', 'aromacak_db30', 's!lver01', 'aromacak_db30')
#2 /home/aromacakes/test.aroma.online/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/aromacake...')
#3 /home/aromacakes/test.aroma.online/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Backend\Block\Templat
```

When i go  to magento admin panel  shows this error
but front end working fine

I clear cache but still not working....
how i can fix this...

Answer (score 1):

As per your error logs it's a **`database credentials`** issue, so double check your **`database settings`** from your **`env.php`** file:

Go to **`app/etc/env.php`** and look for **`db setting`** inside then update or double check below code (if you have the right db credentials inserted):

```
'db' => [
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => 'your host',
            'dbname' => 'your database',
            'username' => 'db user username',
            'password' => 'db user password',
            'active' => '1'
        ]
    ]
],
```

Then run **`cache:flush`**

Try **`hard refresh`**  using **`ctrl + F5`** keyboard command